# jquery: val() method not working

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown element populated through jquery ajax

```
    <select name="category" class="form-control"></select>
```

This is the jquery code for populating the dropdown

```
    $.post(
    "get_categories.php",
    {
        id: 1
    }, function(data) {
        $($('select[name=category]')).html(data);

    }
);
```

To see whether the dropdown was successfully populated i use console.log

```
     }, function(data) {
        $($('select[name=category]')).html(data);
        console.log(data)
    }
```

This is what i've got in the browser console window

```
    <option value='1'>Stuffed Toy</option><option value='1'>Plushie</option><option value='1'>Memorabilia</option>
```

The dropdown was indeed succesfully populated to test whether value will change when i select another option i included this snippet:

```
    $('select[name=category]').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

After changing options this is what ive got

```
    <option value='1'>Stuffed Toy</option><option value='1'>Plushie</option><option value='1'>Memorabilia</option>
    1
```

value of dropdown wont change at all. What i've been doing wrong?

Comment: What you are expecting...

Answer (score 0):

Your Html  all option  *value='1'*, so you have to find option selected

```
$('select[name=category]').change(function () {
    console.log($(":selected", this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/090w362f/3/)**

Comment: btw this is the php code to populate dropdown
      <?php
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    include 'connect.php';
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM tbl_product";
    $result = db_query($query);
    $count = 1;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $count;
            echo "<option value='".$count."'>".$row['category']."</option>";
            $count++;
            
        }
    }
?>

Comment: I think you count value is not incremented , so  include PHP tag also not only jquery

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from a dropdown you can use native javascript `this.value`.

```
$('select[name=category]').change(function(){
   var selectedValue = this.value;
});
```

First try to see whether the event is getting invoked or not by putting a `console.log` inside the change event.

Comment: Did you noticed his Html ,all option look like **option value='1'**, If select anything it will display 1 only

Comment: Ohh, my bad. Didnt see that.

Comment: but when testing my php code the value to be assigned in the option changed

Answer (score 0):

This is btw the php code

```
    <?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
include 'connect.php';
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM tbl_product";
$result = db_query($query);
$count = 1;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $count;
        echo "<option value='".$count."'>".$row['category']."</option>";
        $count++;
    }
}
```

?>